# How Do I Know That I'm Not Breaking Anything During Refactoring?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, integration-testing

I've started my first experience in refactoring on huge system and writing unit tests for it, but I am just scared that I'm breaking the code without knowing it.
I studied the "the art of unit testing" and "working efficiently with legacy code" to find a solution, and my next plan is just stop refactoring for a while and write some integration testing(I have selected Fitnesse tool for integration testing purpose) to run them every time after I change some thing.
I am just wondering is there any other one with same experience? Do you think inetegration testing can be a good solution for this issue? Do you have any better idea?

I also checked this question ([How can I check that I didn't break anything when refactoring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935331/how-can-i-check-that-i-didnt-break-anything-when-refactoring)) but my situation is different with that, because there is no unit test available and I am here to write unit tests.

Comment: Honestly all the answers you need are in one of the books you cited, Working Effectively with Legacy Code.  Chapter 16: I Don't Understand the Code Well Enough to Change It might be a good start.  More pertinent to your specific question is Chapter 23: How Do I Know That I'm Not Breaking Anything?

Comment: I am dealing with a big system without any documentation just access to programmers who have developed the system in long term and still maintain it. I joined the team recently to help them refactor the system and make it testable, but I am afraid of breaking something so I decided to write integration and acceptance testing to cover whole system and after that start refactoring. I have selected FitNesse for this purpose, but I am not sure now, you have any idea about the tools?

Answer (score 2):

Integration testing is part of a good solution for refactoring.  However some problems introduced by the refactoring will only show up when you have deployed the project.

A better idea would be to incorporate the integration testing into a **[continuous delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery)** strategy.  This means you should have a clean and practical approach to build and deploy the project as often as possible to a near identical environment while refactoring it.  The book [Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment](http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html) is a good resource.  Here is one of the antipatterns it describes (Pages 7-9):

> **Antipattern: Deploying to a Production-like Environment Only after Development Is Complete**
>
> In this pattern, the first time the software is deployed to a
>   production-like environment (for example, staging) is once most of
>   the development work is done...
>
> Once the application is deployed into staging, it is common for new
>   bugs to be found...
>
> The remedy is to integrate the testing, deployment, and release
>   activities into the development process. Make them a normal and
>   ongoing part of development so that by the time you are ready to
>   release your system into production there is little to no risk,
>   because you have rehearsed it on many different occasions in a
>   progressively more production-like sequence of test environments. Make
>   sure everybody involved in the software delivery process, from the
>   build and release team to testers to developers, work together from
>   the start of the project.

Comment: I am dealing with a big system without any documentation just access to programmers who have developed the system in long term and still maintain it. I joined the team recently to help them refactor the system and make it testable, but I am afraid of breaking something so I decided to write integration and acceptance testing to cover whole system and after that start refactoring. I have selected FitNesse for this purpose, but I am not sure now, you have any idea about the tools?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, this is the problem of working with Legacy Code.

Integration Tests are your best bet, but to write those to correctly meet your needs, you would need to know the original intent of the original code, which often isn't as clear, because there are often hidden requirements.

There are no ideal solutions.

Comment: I am dealing with a big system without any documentation just access to programmers who have developed the system in long term and still maintain it. I joined the team recently to help them refactor the system and make it testable, but I am afraid of breaking something so I decided to write integration and acceptance testing to cover whole system and after that start refactoring. I have selected FitNesse for this purpose, but I am not sure now, you have any idea about the tools?

Answer (score 1):

Although previous answers are very good, I'd like to add that unit tests are exactly for this. In our test project when we refactor each other components, its mandatory to run already existing unit tests prepared from initial developer + new ones **before commit** to the Version control. Besides - its a good approach to have *[smoke](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software))* tests running on every check-in. An ofcourse - Integration, Regression etc. afterwards.

*UPDATE*

I'm in the exact same situation - chained to maintenance. Tools can vary greatly - depending of the needs. Starting from Web-, -Unit-Testing up to SOA- and Server-testing. If you provide more detailed info about your [SUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) I'll gladly try to help.

Comment: I am dealing with a big system without any documentation just access to programmers who have developed the system in long term and still maintain it. I joined the team recently to help them refactor the system and make it testable, but I am afraid of breaking something so I decided to write integration and acceptance testing to cover whole system and after that start refactoring. I have selected FitNesse for this purpose, but I am not sure now, you have any idea about the tools?